# Type inference failed in kotlin

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I created an extension function `iterator()` on `JSONArray` class and while using in for loop i am getting below error:

```
Type inferece failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 
operator fun <T> JSONArray.iterator () L Iterator<T>
```

My code is:

```
class GetFlickrJsonData(private val mCallBack: OnDataAvailable, private var mBaseUrl: String, private var mLanguage: String, private var mMatchAll: Boolean) : GetRawData.OnDownLoadComplete {

init {
    Log.d(TAG,"GetFlickrJsonData Called")
}
companion object {
    private val TAG = "GetFlickrJsonData"
}
private var mPhotosList: List<Photo>? = null

interface OnDataAvailable {
    fun onDataAvailable(data: List<Photo>,status: ClientInfoStatus)
}

fun executeOnSameThread(searchCriteria: String){
    Log.d(TAG,"executeOnSameThread starts...")
    val destinationUri: String = createUri(searchCriteria,mLanguage,mMatchAll)
    val getRawData = GetRawData(this)
    getRawData.execute(destinationUri)
    Log.d(TAG,"executeOnSameThread ends...")

}

fun createUri(searchCriteria: String,mLanguage: String,mMatchAll: Boolean): String{
    Log.d(TAG,"createUri starts...")

    return Uri.parse(mBaseUrl).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("tags",searchCriteria)
            .appendQueryParameter("tagmode",if(mMatchAll) "ALL" else "ANY")
            .appendQueryParameter("lang",mLanguage)
            .appendQueryParameter("format","json")
            .appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback","1")
            .build().toString()

}

override fun onDownloadComplete(data: String?, status: DownloadStatus) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onDownLoadComplete  : $status")
    if (status == DownloadStatus.OK) mPhotosList = ArrayList()

    try {
        val jsonData = JSONObject(data)
        val jsonArray: JSONArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("items")
        for (item: JSONObject in jsonArray){

        }
    }

}
```

}

Extension function is:

```
operator fun <T>JSONArray.iterator(): Iterator<T> = (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as T }.iterator()
```

How can i infer it explicitly?

Comment: That is filed as a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22560